# Could not load file or assembly after visual basic publishing

Tags: vb.net

How do I fix the error “System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FontAwesome.Sharp”? i get it after pulishing my vb.net windows form application.

Comment: have you checked to see if the FontAwesome.Sharp assembly exists in your application directory at runtime or in the Global Assembly Cache of target computer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the *References* page of the project properties. Each reference has a `Copy Local` property. If that is set to `True`, the assembly will be copied to the output folder when you build, so it can be deployed along with the application EXE. Only set that to `False` if you expect the assembly to be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) on target machines. If the assembly is in the GAC on your development machine then that property will be set to `False` by default.